# Stack Exchange's rich text editor -- is it available somewhere?

Tags: discussion

I am looking for a good, solid, rich text editor for my ASP.NET web app (3.5).

I know there are some out there and I've been looking around for a while with no luck.  Does anyone know if the one the Stack Exchange uses (the one I'm typing in right now) is available somewhere?

Your help/guidance is appreciated!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The Stack Exchange uses [WMD Editor](http://wmd-editor.com/).

FCKEditor is also easy to [integrate with ASP .NET](http://docs.fckeditor.net/FCKeditor_2.x/Developers_Guide/Integration/ASP.NET).

You have also more options like:

- [RTE (Rich Text Editor ASP.NET Control)](http://www.codeplex.com/rte)
- [Component ART Editor for ASP .NET](http://www.componentart.com/webui/editor.aspx)

Comment: For PhiLho's sake, and probably yours too, I'll put my thank you here.

"Excellent. Thank you CMS!"

Comment: You're welcome deadbug!

Comment: The SO guys have also been doing some work on the editor: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/updated-wmd-editor/
The code can be found here: http://github.com/derobins/wmd/tree/master